# Receive tcp traffic sent to other device

Tags: tcp, mirroring

A server (A) is sending tcp packages to a mission critical alarm system (B).

My server (C) needs to listen to this traffic and generate a statistic of triggered alarms. I do not want to be a man-in-the-middle since the alarms need to be triggered even if my server is down.

Is there a device that can forward all traffic aimed at B but mirror it to C? Is there a solution that allows me to listen to the traffic without forwarding it myself?

*Edit*: I do control neither server A nor server B.

Answer (score 0):

iptables extension TEE:

```
The TEE target will clone a packet and redirect this clone to another machine on the local network segment. In other words, the nexthop must be the target, or you will have to configure the nexthop to forward it further if so desired.
--gateway ipaddr
Send the cloned packet to the host reachable at the given IP address. Use of 0.0.0.0 (for IPv4 packets) or :: (IPv6) is invalid.
To forward all incoming traffic on eth0 to an Network Layer logging box:

-t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j TEE --gateway 2001:db8::1
```

Comment: If my server went down this traffic wouldn't be forwarded anymore, right?